# Where should I ask about CNC designs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm asking for a specific type of joint for sheet material.
Woodworking isn't a best fit, since my question is not limited to plywood.
Engineering or DIY seem like too broad a match, I have no hope of getting answers there.

Specifically my question is -- how do I calculate the size of a cutout for such a joint so that a wrench would fit?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [Arts & Crafts](http://crafts.stackexchange.com/)? I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

**Engineering is a good fit**

What you are describing is a part of engineering design. Ensuring there is sufficient clearance is a common engineering problem so they should be able to help.

Disclaimer: I'm not on Engineering.SE but I am a professional engineer.